# How to achieve time delay between two callouts?

Tags: apex, callout

I have multiple callouts in one apex method. First callout create Object and second callout fetch created record based on first callout response that contains Object Id. I suppose that the system create record asynchronously. How can I avoid situation when I not able to fetch record which in fact is not created yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are 3 ways you can do it.

1. Using Queuable/Future : They run after the current transaction is completed. There is no SLA so we have no idea when it will it execute, They can execute in just a second or can take hours.
2. Using Scheduler: Scheduler allows you to time the job that you want to execute in future. This kinda helps when you know if that async process will be complete in few minutes/hours.
3. Using Inbound Calls(Apex Rest or Platform Events): Instead of polling ask the 3rd party system to update salesforce the stautus when the processing is complete.

Comment: Chained batch jobs can be an option too as they guarantee the new batch job will start after the current batch job finishes(When called from finish method ), its a nice way to workaround governor limits!

Comment: I think that comes in first point.

Comment: Thanks for all ideas, but what can I do when I need to display created data after second callout from within the same vf pave that create records ?

Comment: I think you are looking for Apex Poller...  Apex Poller in vf allows you to do poll it...

Comment: Finally I used future method and it works like a charm for my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a job which uses the `Queueable` interface. Call your first method, do whatever processing you need, then you can pass along any info over to another `Queueable` job - which calls your second job. If the record is not created when you call the second job, you can always call the second job again, but be aware theres a limit on chained jobs - up to 5 (including the parent) can be chained. Just be sure to include `Database.AllowsCallouts` in your class, or you won't be able to make any callouts.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) for more details.